# Checking the status of a specific rule in Fluent Validation C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am pretty new to [fluent validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/). Somehow I am able to do a validation like this:

```
public class GetPayloadQueryValidator: AbstractValidator<string?>
{
    public GetPayloadQueryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x).NotEmpty().Must(x => isValidJSON(x));
        RuleFor(x => x).NotEmpty().Must(x => isValidRequest(x));
    }

    private bool isValidJSON(string? json)
    {
        try
        {
            JToken jsonToken = JObject.Parse(json);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool isValidRequest(string? json)
    {
        try
        {
            JObject? obj = JObject.Parse(json);

            if (!obj.HasValues)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!obj.ContainsKey("fixed") ||
                    !obj.ContainsKey("data") ||
                    !obj["data"].HasValues)
            {
                return false;
            }

            JObject? data = obj["data"].ToObject<JObject?>();

            if(!data.ContainsKey("templateName") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["templateName"].ToString()) || 
                !data.ContainsKey("primaryObjectName") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["primaryObjectName"].ToString()))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So here first validator is checking the input is just a valid json. Second validator is checking whether it contains few attributes.

So this is how I am validating using that.

```
GetPayloadQueryValidator? QV = new GetPayloadQueryValidator();

ValidationResult? validate = QV.Validate(request.orchestratorData);

if (!validate.IsValid)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Code = "400", Message = "Bad Request" }).ToString();
}
```

But this is just telling me all those validations succeeded or not. But if I need to check the given input string is a valid json (I don't need the attribute check), how I can accomplish that.

More clearly, I need to know is that a valid json rather than just getting it meets all the condition.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WithErrorCode`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/error-codes.html#custom-error-codes) method to say which rule was broken. Also, you don't need to keep using `NotEmpty` on every line since the first rule will catch that. For example:

```
public GetPayloadQueryValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x).NotEmpty().WithErrorCode("ERR1");
    RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => isValidJSON(x)).WithErrorCode("ERR2");
    RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => isValidRequest(x)).WithErrorCode("ERR3");
}
```

And in your validation code:

```
ValidationResult? validate = QV.Validate("");

if (!validate.IsValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not valid because:");
    foreach (var error in validate.Errors)
    {
        // This will print out "ERR1" or "ERR2 or "ERR3" or some combination of them all
        Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorCode);
    }
}
```

Note that if you omit a `WithErrorCode` method after every validator, you will get a code that represents that validation method. For example the `NotEmpty` method will give you `NotEmptyValidator` and `Must` gives you `PredicateValidator`.

Comment: Thats great.. Thank you very much. But sorry, I didnt understand that last sentence.

Comment: Just try out the code you have with my loop to print out the errors, you will see what I mean.